# I'm trying to send 2 digits every time, first one is for On or Off, the second digit is for the delay time

Tags: arduino

I tried it without sending two digits and it works as on or off for the delay time that I set in code.
I believe that the problem is with the `t` value, as the code runs with deleting the `t` from the delay statement.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
    char c;
    int t;
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        c = Serial.read();
        t = Serial.read() - 48; //because when I send numbers from 1-9 it converts it to ascii code
        Serial.println(c);
        Serial.println(t);
        if (c == '1')
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        else
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
    delay(t * 1000);
}
```

I expect the led to lights for 3 seconds and turn off for 2 seconds then lights for 4 if I send `130214`.

Comment: Serial.read() return an `int`, read the [doc](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/).

Comment: Why are you doing like this? read values as String or put an ack between your data. `Serial.read()` would only read the first byte of incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your algorithm, maybe this help you, in these you can creat your own simple communication protocol for your project. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHeG3Gt6STE